# Weighted sum of series in Graphite

Tags: graphite, weighted-average

I'm working with series of response times from different servers in Graphite, and I have separate series showing the number of requests from each server.  Now what I'd like to do is compute a weighted average of these, i.e.

avg = ((weight1 * value1) + (weight2 * value2)) / (weight1 + weight2)

However, I'm having problems computing the top part of this expression.  I've tried inputting:

```
sumSeries(multiplySeries(series1,weights1),multiplySeries(series2,weights2))
```

as a target, but Graphite just renders "no data".  Each of the multiplySeries calls on their own works.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, and was unable to find a decent solution, so I tried to write one - see this pull request: https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/pull/300